# Uninstalling partially installed XCode + iPhone SDK

Tags: xcode, macos, uninstallation

I tried to install XCode + the iPhone SDK on my mac, but the installer ran out of space during install and I'm left with something to the effect of 30 MB free on my hard disk. How do i remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the folder "Developer" in Macintosh HD to the trash, and then empty the trash.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! Just go into your hard drive see the developer folder drag it into trash. Empty that Now Launch the installer for Xcode and it will not see that and just recreate it!